# goldendict XML parse error on Wikipedia and Wiktionary

Tags: xml, translation

I get this error on **goldendict** for **English Wikipedia** and **English Wiktionary**:

```
Query error: XML parse error: unexpected end of file at 1,1
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

This issue is fixed going to the Wikipedia section on goldendict settings:

[image]

and change the `http://` by `https://` in the Address column for the failing Wikipedia or Wiktionary. They were the English urls in my case, so I changed them

[image]

... and everything works OK now

[image]

Comment: To change the URL, double-click on it.

Comment: After applying your fix, I had another error: "SSL handshake failed".. Finally I got it working after building goldendict from source

Comment: For me helped uninstall and reinstalling "32-bit Windows En-Ru-En installer, 78MB" full-weight version: http://goldendict.org/download.php

Comment: @GermanGarcia, same here.  There is a [GitHub issue opened](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/608) on the subject.